# Rename assets to lowercase

Tags: plugin-development, assets

As there is no native config to control the naming of assets I am trying to write a small plugin to do this.
Here is what I have;

```
    craft()->on('assets.saveAsset', function (Event $event) {
        if ($event->params['isNewAsset']) {

            $asset = $event->params['asset'];

            // Set the filename to a variable, appending the file extension
            // $extension = $asset->getExtension();
            // $filename = strtolower($asset->filename.md5(time()).'.'.$asset->getExtension());
            $filename = strtolower($asset->filename.'.'.$asset->getExtension());

            // Rename the file on the server
            craft()->assets->renameFile($asset, $filename);

            // Set filename attribute and re-save asset
            $asset->setAttribute('filename', $filename);
            craft()->assets->storeFile($asset);
        }
    });
```

However, this currently results in a duplication of the extension like so;
model-rendering-image.jpg.jpg
special-services.jpg.jpg

If I remove this part of the code 
`'.'.$asset->getExtension())` then the asset isn't renamed at all.

Can't seem to get past this hurdle.

Anyone able to shed some light?

Also is there a reason that assets are not renamed to lowercase by default or why this isn't rolled in as a config option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change asset name on upload](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13154/change-asset-name-on-upload)

Comment: This is certainly based on that but my question is more specifically about how to remove the duplicate extension in the name.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested your code and it worked as you'd expect if you leave off the extra `getExtension()` call (the `filename` property already includes the extension).

```
$filename = strtolower($asset->filename);
```

If it's not saving for you with that, you've got some other error happening elsewhere.