# Limit slugs to ASCII for auto-generated titles

Tags: craft3, slug, titles, auto-generate

I currently have auto-generated titles that contains accents and so does the slugs.

Since the slug is used to generate assets folders, accents aren't suitable and results in question marks in the folder names.

I was hoping that limitAutoSlugsToAscii would answer this problem but it only affects the javascript for dynamically generated slugs.

Is there a simple way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the slug is used to generate assets folders, accents aren't suitable and results in question marks in the folder names.

You could do something similar to [How to rename filename of asset before (or after) upload in Craft 3](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/28257/how-to-rename-filename-of-asset-before-or-after-upload-in-craft-3) in a plugin except you run the folder name through the same ASCII normalization process that auto-generated slugs go though.